# Using ‘do’ in a sentence

Tags: word-choice

Are both the following sentences correct?

1- I have written many things regarding climate change. Do read them on my website.

2- I have written many things regarding climate change. Read them on my website.

Answer (score 0):

Both are correct. The use of "do" suggests an invitation. It is a bit more formal, and might seem a bit more old-fashioned. There is not a significant difference in meaning, only in tone.

Answer (score 0):

> I have written many things regarding climate change. Do read them on my website.

The use of **'do'** here is expressing politeness. If they want they can head over to your website and read them, otherwise not.

> I have written many things regarding climate change. Read them on my website.

More like an imperative sentence. As if you are commanding them to read otherwise there would be consequences.

Comment: I disagree.  To my American ear, the latter version is an entirely normal thing to say and not commanding or threatening in any way.

Comment: @DarthPseudonym It might be that Indians take more offence in everything.

Answer (score 0):

Most American English speakers would not use 'do' in this context. While it isn't strictly invalid, to my ear, using 'do' here makes you sound like a rather old-fashioned British person, where 'do' stands in for "Please do" in an invitation -- "Oh, do come over when you have a chance!"

In my opinion, if you feel "Read them on my website" is a little too imperious, it would be better to say "You may read them on my website" or "They are available on my website".

Comment: *Please do* go and read them, for example, is used in AmE.